# Aggregate SpatialPoint to form SpatialPolygon

Tags: r, aggregation, sp

Is it possible to convert SpatialPointDataFrame to SpatialPolygonDataFrame by some kind of generalization or aggregation function in R.

how can i form polygons from points of similar color/classified attribute value as show in picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do it via `raster`, as long as your points really are regular and the values are discrete (for dissolve) this should work:

```
library(raster)
## x is the SpatialPointsDataFrame
r <- rasterFromXYZ(x)
## create polygons on unique values
p <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)
```

Here's an example

```
library(raster)
x <- as(raster(volcano%/% 10) * 10, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
r <- rasterFromXYZ(x)
## create polygons on unique values
p <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = TRUE)
plot(p, col = topo.colors(nrow(p))[factor(p$layer)])
```

[image: discretized polygonized volcano]

Answer (score 2):

have a look at the examples in sp:

```
library(sp)
example(aggregate)
```

[image]